# How to deactivate a user in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need help to deactivate a user from the front end yet keep it's details in the backend. I am using CodeIgniter and very new to it.

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {


        $data = $this->customer_m->array_from_post(array('customer_id','is_disable') );

        $this->session->set_flashdata('success','Customer details updated successfully.');

        redirect('bulkedit/index');

    }
```

This is the code I have used to remove the customer from the table. It must remain in the backend.

Comment: Does the code give you a problem? Not work? Etc? You need full information. Also, the entire question should be in they body of the question, not in the title

Comment: Simply keep a field in your users table (say, account_status) and set and unset it by giving 0 and 1 as values. 
i.e. upon delete the field should be set to 0 otherwise it will be 1.

Then add a check at your login page. Allow user logged in only if the field is set 1.

Comment: @ash_8247 i have done that, the only person who will use this is the admin, it is just to record all the users that have subscribed to the particular course.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add one field "is_deleted" (default value:0) to your users table which will identify if user is deactivated from frontend. When user is deactivated from front, update this field with "1" so your user will be there in backend safe but deactivated from front with query is_deleted=0

Comment: hi disha, thanks for the reply, i have made an is_disable option in the database whichever, wherein the user which is disabled = 1,however it doesn't reflect the same in the frontend, as it is still showing in the table (frontend) irrespective of the user being is_disable=1

Comment: Yes, you need to query users which is_deleted=0 in frontend for that.

Comment: i am sorry i am still new to this, i have added a query but it didn't seem to work $this->db->query->("SELECT customer_id from dance_customer where is_disable=0"); this is the query i have added in the controller, is there something wrong in this code?